# Click event handler not getting called

Tags: c++-cli, windows-forms-designer

I'm using or 'learning' C++/CLI because I like the look of the GUI, and I'm trying to trigger some event when the mouse is over the picture and when it's out of the picture, but it doesn't work, and the only event that work is when the mouse clicks on the picture.

My code is down below

```
void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^ ) {
    label1->Text = String::Concat( sender->GetType(), ": Enter" );
}

void pictureBox1_MouseHover(Object^ sender,  System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^ ) {
    label1->Text = String::Concat( sender->GetType(), ": MouseHover" );
}

void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(Object^ sender,  System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^ ) {
    label1->Text = String::Concat( sender->GetType(), ": MouseLeave" );
}

private: System::Void pictureBox1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    label1->Text = String::Concat( sender->GetType(), ": Click" );
}
```

Comment: What does "Doesn't work" mean? Do you mean it never gets called, or it doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: yes it never get called and dosent do anything

Comment: C# is very similar in the struktur so maybe someone would now the awnser

Comment: If you like the look of the WinForms GUI, do consider learning C# instead. C++/CLI is primarily for interop between unmanaged and managed code, C# is the recommended language for developing new applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's your entire code, then all you've done is define some methods. The UI doesn't know that it's supposed to call them when those events happen.

What you need to do is add event handlers on the various objects. Create a delegate from your local method, and add that (using the `+=` operator) to the event.

[MouseEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseenter.aspx), [MouseHover](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover.aspx), and [MouseLeave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseleave.aspx) are all defined as [EventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx), not [MouseEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventhandler.aspx). That means that the method should take an [EventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.aspx), not a [MouseEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.aspx), so switch your method declarations.

```
// Do this in the constructor.
this->pictureBox1->MouseEnter += gcnew EventHandler(this, &Form1::pictureBox1_MouseEnter);
this->pictureBox1->MouseHover += gcnew EventHandler(this, &Form1::pictureBox1_MouseHover);
this->pictureBox1->MouseLeave += gcnew EventHandler(this, &Form1::pictureBox1_MouseLeave);

this->pictureBox1->Click += gcnew EventHandler(this, &Form1::pictureBox1_Click);
```

Comment: but it says  error C2664: 'System::Windows::Forms::Control::MouseEnter::add' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventHandler ^' to 'System::EventHandler ^'

Comment: Ah, I didn't check the definitions of the events you used. All three of those methods are defined as EventHandler, not MouseEventHandler. You'll need to change your method definitions as well.

Comment: i changed it as you told me and now it says error C3352: 'void winformsapp::Form1::pictureBox1_MouseEnter(System::Object ^,System::EventArgs)' : the specified function does not match the delegate type 'void (System::Object ^,System::EventArgs ^)'

Comment: Looks like you forgot a `^` in the updated method declaration.

Comment: MouseDown and MouseUp take a MouseEventArgs, so that would be `gcnew MouseEventHandler`. The MouseEventArgs will tell you things such as which button was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to add those methods as callbacks

Comment: as i'm new into all this. Could you please explain more and show me example of se methods as callbacks implanted right+

Comment: i dont really understand this example